# How to show my pictures folder in a xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I´m new on this site, I have too much troubles with a code for Kinect that I extracted from a few samples. What I want to do is to show the pictures in My Pictures folder in `XAML`, like in the SlideShow sample, but I don´t want to change the pictures with a slide. I want to change them with a voice command. The problem is when I copy-paste the code from the SlideShow, the pictures don´t show up.

**XAML**

```
<Grid Row="1">
    <Image x:Name="next" Source="{Binding NextPicture}" Opacity="0"/>
    <Image x:Name="previous" Source="{Binding PreviousPicture}" Opacity="0"/>
    <Image x:Name="current" Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
</Grid>
```

**XAML.CS**

```
private readonly string[] picturePaths = CreatePicturePaths();

/// <summary>
/// Gets the previous image displayed.
/// </summary>
public BitmapImage PreviousPicture { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets the current image to be displayed.
/// </summary>
public BitmapImage Picture { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets teh next image displayed.
/// </summary>
public BitmapImage NextPicture { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Get list of files to display as pictures.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Paths to pictures.</returns>
private static string[] CreatePicturePaths()
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    var commonPicturesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures);
    list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(commonPicturesPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(commonPicturesPath, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }

    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        var myPicturesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(myPicturesPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(commonPicturesPath, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
    }

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You can't just dump all your code here and expect others to debug it for you.  You must first debug it, then if you are confused why something isn't working correctly, come and show us 1) what bit of code isn't working 2) what it does 3) what you want it to do.  Go start reading here to learn how to debug https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you tell what is the specific problem you have? You should also try to reduce the code to only the parts related to the problem.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, I updated my post, I hope is better.

Comment: Please do not consider StackOverflow (SO) as quick solution guide or code writing service altogether. Follow the suggestions above. Remember, a well posted question (adhering to SO guidelines) will always be read and answered seriously; no matter if it's basic or complex question. Otherwise you will see nothing but such comments on your questions. Always!

Comment: You don't seem to actually set PreviousPicture/Picture/NextPicture anywhere.

Comment: Thanks to all, but the problem was that I have one method WindowLoaded and one method OnWindowLoaded, the pictures should came up on the WindowLoaded but this method never happens.